# How to merge two tables and sum the values with the same ID in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am new to SQL sorry if the question ends up being trivial.

I have two tables:

**Table 1 "Clients":**

```
 CREATE TABLE customer (ID, Name, Surname);
 INSERT INTO customer (ID, Name, Surname)
 VALUES (1, 'Smith', 'Hulk'),
 (2, 'Jake', 'Brook'),
 (3, 'Vladimir', 'Computin'),
 (4, 'Joe', 'Door');
```

**Table 2 "Payments":**

```
 CREATE TABLE payment (payment_id, customer_id, payment_date, payment_amount);
 INSERT INTO payment (payment_id, customer_id, payment_date, payment_amount)
 VALUES (1, 1, "11/09/2011", 100),
 (2, 2, "15/10/2013", 50),
 (3, 4, "2/1/2011", 30),
 (4, 3, "12/09/2011", 200),
 (5, 2, "15/10/2013", 200),
 (6, 3, "2/1/2011", 10),
 (7, 1, "11/09/2011", 120),
 (8, 4, "15/10/2013", 100);
```

**Desired Output:**

```
CREATE TABLE payment (Name, Surname, total_payments);
 INSERT INTO payment (Name, Surname, total_payments)
 VALUES ('Smith', 'Hulk',220),
 ('Jake', 'Brook', 250),
 ('Vladimir', 'Computin', 210),
 ('Joe', 'Door', 130)
```

**Here is what I have tried:**

```
SELECT payments.ID, sum(payments.payment_amount)
FROM payments
GROUP BY payments.ID
```

This sums the entries in table "payments" with the same ID.

However, I don't know how to use the ID in order to have Name and Surname in front of total_payments (like in desired output).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to first JOIN your two tables together.  You are needing to find the 'Relationship'  between your tables so you can pull together the payments along with the customer who who made that payment. Before you start applying Group By clauses to your query first write the JOINs to relate your data.  In this case you would JOIN your tables by Customer_ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can need `JOIN` to bring them into the query and then appropriate aggregation:

```
SELECT c.ID, c.Name, c.SurName, sum(p.payment_amount)
FROM clients c LEFT JOIN
     payments p
     ON c.id = p.customer_id
GROUP BY c.ID, c.Name, c.SurName;
```

Note:  Using a correlated subquery is often faster:

```
SELECT c.*, 
       (SELECT SUM(p.payment_amount)
        FROM payments p
        WHERE c.id = p.customer_id
       ) as total_payments
FROM clients c ;
```

In particular, this can efficiently use an index on `payments(customer_id, payment_amount)`.

Comment: Thank you! this is just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You need a `LEFT` join (just in case a customer does not have any payments) of `customer` to `payment` and aggregation:

```
SELECT c.Name, c.Surname, 
       COALESCE(SUM(p.payment_amount), 0) payment_amount
FROM customer c LEFT JOIN payment p
ON p.customer_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.ID, c.Name, c.Surname
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0f6c6b9277fa4fac9350d6fd6bf3add6).
Results:

```
> Name     | Surname  | payment_amount
> :------- | :------- | -------------:
> Smith    | Hulk     |            220
> Jake     | Brook    |            250
> Vladimir | Computin |            210
> Joe      | Door     |            130
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply its works perfectly! and thanks for letting me know about the  https://dbfiddle.uk/!! great resource! It's a shame that I can accept only one answer.

Comment: @Geom is there a reason that you accepted the latest answer?

Comment: no technical reason. It's just Occam's razor. Somehow simplest solution always attracts. I am unfortunately not familiar with "COALESCE" yet so I understood what's going on in the other solution better. I wish there was a way to accept both answers since both helped me a lot!

Comment: @Geom *...not familiar with "COALESCE"...* then you should look it up. You need coalesce() just in case a customer does not have any payments so you get 0 as result and not NULL.

Comment: I will, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
select c.Name, c.Surname, SUM(p.payment_amount)
from Payments as p, Clients as c
where p.customerID = c.ID
group by c.Name, c.Surname
```

I think it will work

Comment: Thanks for your reply! technically it works but for some reason, it changed the order of the raws. :/